# Memory management in Corona sdk when using physics objects in the application

Tags: coronasdk

How to remove physics objects from memory after pausing physics and removing that object from physics ?

Comment: Combine a physics object with its anti-object; the result will be empty memory and a photon.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the object from from physic simulation do the following

```
result = physics.removeBody( physicsObject)
```

This will remove object from physics as well as from memory

```
physicsObject:removeSelf()
physicsObjet = nil
```